# take php string which contains square brackets as string not array

Tags: php, arrays, string, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have a weird problem here. I'm using an associative array in php (using cakePHP) which has the following form:

```
$my_array = array(
     'data['a']['b'] => 'value1', 
     'data['b']['c'] => 'value2', 
     'data['b']['d'] => 'value3', 
     'data['e'] => array(
            'data['e1']['e2']' => 'value3', 
            'data['e1']['e3']' => 'value4'));
```

The problem I'm having is that

```
'data['e1']['e2']' => 'value3' and 'data['e1']['e3']' => 'value4'
```

are taken like an array like this:

```
'data['e1']' => array(
     ['e2'] => 'value3', 
     ['e3'] => 'value4');
```

I don't want these to be taken as arrays, I want them to be taken as key and value of the array 'data['e']'. As a matter of fact, I want all the elements of the arrays $my_array and 'data['e']' to be taken as keys and values of the corresponding array (not as arrays).

Any help please?

P.S This seems to happen only when I do a debug on cakePHP, if I don't use cakePHP everything seems to be fine and "data" comes from a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) posted data to cakePHP

Comment: `'data['a']['b'] => 'value1'` is most certainly invalid syntax. Where does that data come from? How is it treated as array? Please show a more complete example.

Comment: "data" comes from a cURL posted data to cakePHP

Comment: If you POST data like `data[Foo][bar]=baz&data[Foo][baz]=bar` to Cake, then yes, it's treated as an array. In fact, even normal PHP would treat that as an array. Is that your question?

Comment: So there's no way to get for example data[Foo][bar]=baz as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid PHP. My best guess is that it should look like this:

```
$my_array = array(
     $data['a']['b'] => 'value1',
     $data['b']['c'] => 'value2',
     $data['b']['d'] => 'value3',
     $data['e'] => array(
            $data['e1']['e2'] => 'value3',
            $data['e1']['e3'] => 'value4'));
```

Please show us the contents (for instance, using `print_r`) of $data.

Answer (score 0):

POSTed data in a [certain syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) is automatically parsed into `$_POST` as array. If you want to get the raw input, use `file_get_contents('php://input')`. See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php.